# Share SparkContext between Java and R Apps under the same Master

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

So here is the setup.

Currently I have two Spark Applications initialized. I need to pass data between them (preferably through shared sparkcontext/sqlcontext so I can just query a temp table). I currently use Parquet Files to dataframe transfer, but is it possible any other way?

MasterURL points to the same SparkMaster

Start Spark via Terminal:

```
/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh; 
/opt/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://`hostname`:7077
```

Java App Setup:

```
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
//conf = setMaster(MasterURL), 6G memory, and 4 cores.
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(parentContext.sc());
```

Then I register an existing frame later on

```
//existing dataframe to temptable
df.registerTempTable("table");
```

and

SparkR

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master='MasterURL', sparkEnvir=list(spark.executor.memory='6G', spark.cores.max='4')
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

# attempt to get temptable
df <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT * FROM table"); # throws the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible given your current configuration. Tables created using `registerTempTable` are bound to the specific `SQLContext` which has been used to create corresponding `DataFrame`. Even if your Java and SparkR applications use the same master their drivers run on separate JVMs and cannot share single `SQLContext`.

There are tools, like Apache Zeppelin, which take a different approach with a single `SQLContext` (and `SparkContext`) which is exposed to individual backends. This way you can register table using for example Scala and read it from Python. There is [a fork of Zeppelin which provides some support for SparkR and R](https://github.com/datalayer/datalayer-zeppelin). You can check how it [starts and interacts R backend](https://github.com/datalayer/datalayer-zeppelin/blob/rscala/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/ZeppelinR.scala).