# How to cache a Spark data frame and reference it in another script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to cache a data frame and then reference (query) it in another script?...My goal is as follows:

1. In script 1, create a data frame (df)
2. Run script 1 and cache df
3. In script 2, query data in df

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible using standard Spark binaries. Spark `DataFrame` is bound to the specific `SQLContext` which has been used to create it and is not accessible outside it.

There are tools, like for example Apache Zeppelin or Databricks, which use shared context injected into different sessions. This is way you can share temporary tables between different sessions and or guest languages.

There are other platforms, including [`spark-jobserver`](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) and [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/spark/shared-memory-layer.html), which provide alternative ways to share distributed data structures. You can also take a look at the [Livy server](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/spark/java#welcome-to-livy-the-rest-spark-server).

See also: [Share SparkContext between Java and R Apps under the same Master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35371667/1560062)

Answer (score 0):

You could also persist the actual data to a file / database and load it up again. Spark provides methods to do this so you don't need to collect the data to the driver.