# Spark tables visibility across multiple python scripts

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.4.0 on an AWS cluster. The purpose is ETL and it is heavily based on Spark SQL using pyspark.
I have a multitude of python scripts that are invoked in sequence. There are data dependencies between these scripts. There is a main.py that invokes other scripts like process1.py, process2.py etc.

The invocation is done using:

```
#invoking process 1
command1 = "/anaconda3/bin/python3  process1.py"
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command1.split(" "), stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait() 

#invoking process 2
command2 = "/anaconda3/bin/python3  process2.py"
p2 = subprocess.Popen(command2.split(" "), stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.wait()
```

Each of these processes (process1.py, process2.py etc ) are doing dataframe transformations using SQL based syntax like:

```
df_1. createGlobalTempView ('table_1')
result_1 = spark.sql('select * from table_1 where <some conditions>')
```

The challenge is that I want dataframes (like `df_1` or `result_1`) and/or tables (like `table_1`) to be accessible across the processing sequence. So, for example if the code above is in process1.py the generated `df_1` or `table_1` to be accessible in process2.py.

Main.py, process1.py and process2.py are getting the spark session using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-spark").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
```

I know there is the option to use HIVE for storing `table_1` but I am trying to avoid if possible this scenario.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cache a Spark data frame and reference it in another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583493/how-to-cache-a-spark-data-frame-and-reference-it-in-another-script)

Comment: Not really, because @dagspark is already using global views

Comment: Do both Spark jobs have access to the same metastore? If you aren't using Hive as a centralized metastore, you have to make sure that the local metastore is accessible to both jobs, and also correctly synced. I would recommend debugging along that avenue.

Comment: Rick - yes I checked (with spark.catalog.listDatabases()) and both of them are using the same  METASTORE:::[Database(name='default', description='default database', locationUri='file:/Users/me/Desktop/Spark-stuff/spark-warehouse')]. Everything seems to be in the right place but still not resolution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491972/how-can-i-tear-down-a-sparksession-and-create-a-new-one-within-one-application) provides and implicit answer ...