# Connecting to an existing Spark SQL context in Spark Shell

Tags: shell, apache-spark-sql

I've a Spark SQL application in which I've created DataFrames and have them registered as temporary tables. Now, I wish to use Spark Shell to connect to the context in this app so that I can do some exploratory analysis.

I've done some searching across the Internet but no success so far. I'm still continuing my search, but  I'm hoping someone here have encountered this challenge before and doesn't mind sharing how they resolved it.

Comment: I just test the code on small data samples in spark-shell and then when all small parts work, add them up to the whole application and then compile the Scala .jar file. If there's a better way, I would like to hear as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35371667/1560062

Comment: Thanks, @zero323. I guess I'll have to look for another way,